# F# Interactive Developement DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\MyFolder\'

Tags: f#, directory, f#-interactive, getfiles

When using F# interactive apparently this line of code will search in the path shown in the subject line.

```
let files = Directory.GetFiles("MyFolderPath")
```

Is there any way to set interactive to search the same folder the current fsx file is running from?  Or any way to control this behavior at all?  I'm used to the search starting in bin\Debug obviously and this behavior is throwing me off.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends from where the process fsi.exe is started. Fsi is separated from the IDE, it doesn't know which file is open. When you run Visual Studio, the current directory for fsi is the temp folder.

If you run the fsx file (`fsi foo.fsx` or right-click "Run with F# Interactive"), fsi will run from current directory.

To see where you are (in which directory), you can do:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

To change directory, use this command:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

F# interactive is completely independent of the current F# program (in fact, think of it as running in a separate CMD shell). So I'm afraid, there won't be a simple way to get the currently opened .fsx file.

You might be able to pull something from `fsi.CommandLineArgs` but I have no VS at hand to confirm this.